# How I can print characters from various alphabets in python 3?

Tags: python, encoding, cyrillic

I am trying to work with cyrillic alphabet and latin alphabet with central european characters, however I am not able to print cyrillic characters. Take a look at the sample code below.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print("ň")
print("ф")
```

I've been able to output "ň", once I have set "encoding": "cp1250" in Python.sublime-settings, but unfortunately I have not found any means of displaying cyrillic character.

Thanks for any help.

------------------------Edit--------------------------

meanwhile I've put together code, that works in Ubuntu 13.04 environment but throwing exception in Win 7.

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\branislavs\docs\personal\scripts\playground.py", line 6, in <module>
    for line in data:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1250.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 51: character maps to <undefined>
```

Environment:
Win 7
Python 3.4,
Sublime Text 2,
I am trying to output it on windows console.

What should in win to make it work?

I am pasting the code as well:

```
import sys

char_mapping = ("абвгґдезіийклмнопрстуфъыьцчжшАБВГҐДЕЗIИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФЪЫЬЦЧЖШ",
                "abvhgdeziyjklmnoprstuf'ŷ'cčžšABVHGDEZIYJKLMNOPRSTUF'Ŷ'cČŽŠ")


syllable_mapping = {
    "special": { #di ti ni li, da ta na la, cja, cji, sja, sji, rja, rji
        "ďi": "дї",
        "Ďi": "Дї",
        "ťi": "тї",
        "Ťi": "Тї",
        "ňi": "нї",
        "Ňi": "Нї",
        "ľi": "лї",
        "Ľi": "Лї", 

        "ďa": "дя",
        "Ďa": "Дя",
        "ťa": "тя",
        "Ťa": "Тя",
        "ňa": "ня",
        "Ňa": "Hя",
        "ľa": "ля",
        "Ľa": "Ля",

        "c'a": "ця",
        "c'a": "Ця",
        "c'i": "цї",
        "C'i": "Цї",
        "c'o": "цё", 
        "C'o": "Цё", 

        "s'a": "ся",
        "S'a": "Ся",
        "s'i": "сї",
        "S'i": "Сї",
        "s'o": "сё", 
        "S'o": "Сё", 

        "r'a": "ря",
        "R'a": "Ря",
        "r'i": "рї",
        "R'i": "Рї",
        "r'o": "рё", 
        "R'o": "Рё", 

        "z'a": "зя", 
        "Z'a": "Зя", 
        "z'i": "зї",
        "Z'i": "Зї",
        "z'o": "зё", 
        "Z'o": "Зё", 
    },

    "carons": {
        "ď": "дь",
        "Ď": "Дь",
        "ť": "ть",
        "Ť": "Ть",
        "ň": "нь",
        "Ň": "Нь",
        "ľ": "ль",
        "Ľ": "Ль",

    },

    "basic"  : {
        "ja": "я",
        "Ja": "Я",
        "ju": "ю",
        "Ju": "Ю",
        "je": "є",        
        "Je": "Є",        
        "ch": "х",
        "Ch": "X",
        "'o": "ё",
        "'O": "Ë",
        "x": "кc",
        "X": "Кc",
        "šč": "щ",
        "Šč": "Щ",
        "ji": "ї",

        "c'" : "ць",
        "C'" : "Ць",
        "s'" : "сь",
        "S'" : "Сь",
        "r'" : "рь",
        "R'" : "Рь",        
        "z'" : "зь",
        "Z'" : "Зь",
    }

}



tr_azb_lat = {ord(a):ord(b) for a, b in zip(*char_mapping)}
tr_lat_azb = {ord(b):ord(a) for a, b in zip(*char_mapping)}

def map_syllables_azb_lat(string, mapping_option):
    for rule in syllable_mapping[mapping_option]:
        string = string.replace(syllable_mapping[mapping_option][rule], rule)
    return string

def translit_azb_lat(string):
    string = map_syllables_azb_lat(string, 'special')
    string = map_syllables_azb_lat(string, 'carons')
    string = map_syllables_azb_lat(string, 'basic')
    return string.translate(tr_azb_lat).encode('utf-8').decode(sys.stdout.encoding)

def map_syllables_lat_azb(string, mapping_option):
    for rule in syllable_mapping[mapping_option]:
        string = string.replace(rule, syllable_mapping[mapping_option][rule])
    return string


def translit_lat_azb(string):
    string = map_syllables_lat_azb(string, 'special')
    string = map_syllables_lat_azb(string, 'carons')
    string = map_syllables_lat_azb(string, 'basic')
    return string.translate(tr_lat_azb).encode('utf-8').decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
```

Comment: Works fine here. Feel free to describe your environment.

Comment: Apart from having "coding etc." ontop of the file, is the file actually saved as UTF-8 text? Besides, Python3 does not need the `coding` part, since it defaults to UTF-8 already.

Comment: Where are you trying to output it? Windows console? Linux console?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo - are you certain that the default is utf-8? According to PEP0263, the default is ascii: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: @Robᵩ: Parens after `print`. And the title.

Comment: @Robᵩ "The default encoding for Python source code is UTF-8" (second paragraph, [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type)). The PEP you linked applies to Python 2.x AFAIK

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo - Thanks -- I should have noticed.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have updated the original problem, that currently work in Linux but not in Win. Could you, please, take a look at it? Thanks!